# How to return 0 instead of no row with Count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
I have a query:

SELECT     Store_Number, COALESCE (COUNT(Invoice_Number), 0) AS abc
FROM        Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE     (Invoice_Date BETWEEN @start AND @end) AND (Invoice_Detail_Code IN ('abc'))
GROUP BY Store_Number
```

It's returning:

```
Store Number       ABC
1                  1
3                  23
4                  24
5                  7
```

I'd like it to return:

```
Store Number       ABC
1                  1
2                  0
3                  23
4                  24
5                  7
```

I'm assuming it's because of my "Group By".  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Add a case statement that returns a default (else) of "0" if it's blank.  then you'll get something in that row no matter what.

Comment: I tried that... Didn't work.

Comment: You have to use another table as the base table for your query. If you have no row with a store number of 2 the query will not just create it for you. Look up a tally or numbers table. That is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method . . . if it works . . . is to use conditional aggregation instead of a `where` clause.  So if all stores are in the data but they may not have "abc", then

```
SELECT Store_Number, SUM(Invoice_Detail_Code = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS abc
FROM Invoice_Detail_Tb
WHERE Invoice_Date BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY Store_Number;
```

A method that works more consistently assumes you have a `Stores` tables with ll the stores.  Then you just need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.Store_Number, COUNT(id.Store_Number) AS abc
FROM Stores s LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Invoice_Detail_Tb id
     ON s.Store_Number = id.Store_Number AND
        id.Invoice_Date BETWEEN @start AND @end AND
        id.Invoice_Number = 'abc'
GROUP BY s.Store_Number;
```